# Superposition Principle: Parallel Resistance in a current source

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, superposition, resistivity

[image]

Good Day, I would like to ask a question regarding the superposition principle particularly when the current source is the only one active.

The solution to this question is that when the current source is the only one active, they apply a resistance in parallel method. My question is why? why did they apply the resistance in parallel method? [image]

Comment: Thevenin and Norton equivalent ? Be it a few years since I've done homework like this :)

Comment: A current source has infinite impedance theoretically. And it's in parallel to the other two.

Comment: In Fig (c), R1 is in parallel with R2.

Answer (score 2):

It's just because that's how this particular circuit is constructed.

When you evaluate the circuit's response to the current source you "zero" the voltage source. A voltage source of 0 V is effectively equivalent to a short circuit, so the voltage source is replaced with a wire. After making that replacement, it turns out that the two resistors are in parallel.